# XmlSerializer sets array property isFixedSize to true

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm using an XmlSerializer to deserialize some XML into an object. The problem i'm having is once i've deserialized successfully, one of my properties which is an array has the property `isFixedSize` set to true.

I need to add to this array manually at a later stage, but can't.

Here's my object (other properties omitted for brevity)

```
namespace Omeda.Customer
{
    [Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot("Customer")]
    public class Customer : Error
    {
        [XmlArray("CustomerDemographics")]
        [XmlArrayItem("CustomerDemographic", typeof(CustomerDemographic))]
        public Omeda.Customer.CustomerDemographic[] CustomerDemographics { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here's the method I'm using to deserialize (again, code ommitted for brevity)

```
private T request_Get<T>(string url) where T : new()
{
    object returnObject = new T();

    try
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
        request.Headers.Add("x-omeda-appid", this.API_KEY);
        request.Timeout = 50000;

        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                returnObject = (T)serializer.Deserialize(responseStream);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        ...
    }

    return (T)returnObject;
}
```

Once this object is returned, `customer.CustomerDemographics.IsFixedSize` returns true.

Any help on how to get round this, and why this is happening would be great.

Comment: Did you try serializing those CustomerDemographic nodes to a collection instead?

Comment: how do you mean? using a generic instead of an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IsFixedSize` is [always true for an array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zts5bykx.aspx). If you "need to add to this array manually at a later stage", you should not be using an array; you should probably be using a `List<CustomerDemographic>`, or another collection type that can be grown.

Comment: that makes sense now, you always have to give an array a length when you initialize it. thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try serializing those CustomerDemographic nodes to a collection instead?

To do that, change `typeof(CustomerDemographic)` to `typeof(List<CustomerDemographic>)`.
then you'll be able to change items in that collection. Alternatively:

```
var customer = ... //Customer instance
var list = new List<CustomerDemographic>(custeomr.CustomerDemographics);

// change list here: add, remove, replace

customer.CustomerDemographics = list.ToArray();

// continue using customer instance
```